# Consume a SOAP webservice on Worklight

Tags: soap, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

How can I consume a SOAP webservice on Worklight, using HTTP Adapters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either write it on your own, or use the discover web services feature. Either way you need to read the following training module: [HTTP adapter - Communicating with HTTP back-end systems](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/04_02_HTTP_adapter_-_Communicating_with_HTTP_back-end_systems.pdf).

- For manually writing the SOAP envalope, etc, see slide #20
- For using the discover web services feature, see slide #23 ([additional documentation](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/dev/t_using_service_discovery_to_explore_back-end_services.html?lang=en))

Comment: Thank you! The additional documentation is perfect for this!